# Console Keyboard hit detection and interpretting

Tags: c++, keyboard, console, keypress

Hey so it's been reccomended to me that i should use the kdhit() function to detect a keypress in a console window:

"If it's Windows, the kbhit( ) function is the guy you want. If it's *nix, here's a kbhit( ) emulator. kbhit( ) returns immediately (no blocking) with a flag that says that there is or is not a keyboard character waiting to be read. You can test the flag to see if you should issue a keyboard read."

However i would like to know the easiest, hopefully standard way of reading the key buffer or what he calls the flag. Any tips? **Thanks!**

Comment: No standard way to do anything with the keyboard (you can only read bytes from STDIN as a stream context). You will have to stick to platform-specific stuffs.

Comment: The C++ standard committee hasn't yet managed to agree that computers commonly have keyboards.  Admittedly some don't.  Accordingly, the standard library doesn't have any support for anything as fancy as a 'key was hit' function.  You'll have to use a non-standard support function, available in most any real CRT implementations.  Like _kbhit().  Check the docs of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use _kbhit() to test if a key is pressed. and when it is use _getch() to get the value. (note _getch() can return 0 or 0xE0 for special keys and call _getch() again for that value)
for displaying the characters while reading use _getche().

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way to do this, because, as noted, there's no guarantee that your application is running on a machine that even has a keyboard device, and how one performs user interface functions like this even when there *is* a keyboard varies hugely from platform to platform.

On that score, whoever told you that `kbhit()` was a Windows function misinformed you.  [`kbhit()`, `getch()` and their relatives are actually part of the (C language bindings to the) **MS-DOS** API.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dos-api-bindings.html)  Their presence in the runtime libraries for OS/2, Win32, and other C/C++ compilers is simply to be *a porting aid for MS/PC/DR-DOS programs*.  The library maps them onto whatever *native* mechanism exists for accessing the keyboard, if there is one at all, and usually only in the right way for TUI, not GUI, applications to access the keyboard.

If you're writing a new TUI application, don't use the MS-DOS API.  Use the proper, native, API for the platform that you're targetting, such as the [Win32 Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or the [OS/2 Console API](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/conapi.html), or the [POSIX General Terminal Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/terminal/info) (via ncurses or some such).

Answer (score 2):

Very usefull is GetAsyncKeyState

Check it out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx